# How can a make a CALayer's shadow show up behind a semitransparent layer

Tags: ios, calayer

I'm trying to get a drop shadow to show up behind a shape.
Here is an example of what I want it to look like:
[image]

And Here is and example of what I'm getting with my code:
[image]

Notice that the shadow is not visible behind the transparent shape. Is there any way to use the layer's to render a shadow behind a transparent shape?

```
// self is a subclass of a CALayer
self.opacity = opacity
self.shadowColor = color.cgColor
self.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadow.x, height: shadow.y)
self.shadowRadius = CGFloat(shadow.blur)
self.shadowOpacity = 1
```

Comment: Not built in. But you could draw a blurry shadow in front so it looks like your picture.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said in comment you should add shadow in front of your layer. Here is my proposition for the solution, (add transparent layer in front and create shadow path for it):

```
class FrontShadowLayer: CALayer {

private let shadowLayer: CALayer

override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        updateShadowPath()
    }
}

override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        updateShadowPath()
    }
}

override init() {
    shadowLayer = CALayer()
    super.init()
    shadowSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    shadowLayer = CALayer()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    shadowSetup()
}

private func shadowSetup() {
    self.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
    shadowLayer.frame = bounds
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    updateShadowPath()
}

private func updateShadowPath() {
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Putting a shadow in front of the layer may give a similar effect, but I need it to _behind_ a transparent layer.  The final result is different.